# Deepstream don't fetch data from RethinkDB table

Tags: javascript, rethinkdb, deepstream.io

Can't fetch data from table I've just created in rethinkDB.

---

I've create a new table in retinkDB - `items`.

And fill it with data:

```
r.db('test').table('items').insert([
    {name: 'qqq'},
    {name: 'www'},
    {name: 'eee'}
])
```

**BUT** `.getList()` never returns table's data:

```
client.record.getList('items') // '.getEntries()' always return []
```

I don't really understand why `.getList('items')` didn't return data from `items` table.

---

I *assume* that this is because entries structure: when you are create entry via deepstream, entry's structure be like:

```
[
 ...
  {
    "_d": {
     "id": "qqq"
     "name": 'qqq' 
    },
    "_v": 0,
    "ds_id":  "qqq"
  }
 ...
]
```

But mine structure is just:

```
[
  {
    "id": 'qqq'
    "name": 'qqq'
  }
]
```

---

**My question is**: How to create table with data in rethinkDB (via script) that would we worked with deepstream?

Answer (score -1):

I've find a solition.

First of all table should be created with proper `primaryKey` === "ds_id":

```
r.db('test')
  .tableCreate('items',
    {
      primaryKey: 'ds_id'
    })
```

And after that you have to insert data with deepstream-like structure:

```
r.db('test').table('items').insert([
  {
    "_d": {
      "id": r.uuid(),
      "name": "qqq"
    },
    "_v": 0,
    "ds_id": r.uuid()
}
])
```

---

**P.S.** to make `_d.id` equal to `ds_id` use this:

```
r.db('test').table('items').forEach(function(c) {
  return r.db('test').table('items').get(c('ds_id')).update(function(row) {
    return {_d: {id: row('ds_id')}};
  });
})
```

This is stupid but I don't know how to do it in more elegant way.

Answer (score -1):

deepstream is designed to manage data for you. Simply by saying

```
var bmw = ds.record.getRecord( 'cars/bmw' )
```

deepstream will create a table called `cars` and store an entry with a primary key of bmw in it. You wouldn't be expected to create the table yourself.

Comment: And how could you create table with data in this case? Hardcode all the data inside code? I asked about script, cause I have to make a migration for DB and need a table filled with data from the begining

Comment: For that I'd suppose your solution below would work. Although you could also iterate through your data and load it into deepstream via the client library